# Cannot deploy to polygon

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Truffle migrate keeps my transaction stuck in pending forever.

From my understanding I'm basically saying here "Whatever it takes, whatever it costs, just do it"; if i keep increasing the gas it runs into the block limit.

What am I doing wrong?

```
matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
        mnemonic: {
          phrase: process.env.MNEMONIC
        },
        providerOrUrl: 'https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/v1/<my_id>',
      }),
      network_id: 137,
      gas: 8000000,
      gasPrice: 100000000000,
    },
```